# box shadow + border-radius on IE not working

Tags: html, css

i have a very strange bug on ie 11 on windows 8.1 64 bit. the box-shadow on div with border-radius set is different from the box-shadow on div WITHOUT any border-radius set (

exemple :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
.switchbtn1.first {border-right:none;border-radius:4px 0 0 4px;}
.switchbtn1.last {border-left:none;border-radius:0 4px 4px 0;}
.switchbtn1 {
  font-size:14px;
  line-height:14px;
  padding:3px 15px 6px;
  border:1px solid #E8BA66;
  float:left;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px rgba(227, 168, 79, 0.6);
}
</style>
</head>

<body>  
  <div class="switchbtn1 first">un</div>
  <div class="switchbtn1">deux</div>
  <div class="switchbtn1 last">trois</div>        
</body>
</html>
```

this result in :

[image]

you see that the box-shadow on the div with round-corner is different from the box-shadow on the div without round-corner ...

this bug not happen on all IE11. for exemple on IE11 on Windows 7 it's seam to not happen

any idea ?

Comment: Did you try with HTML5 doctype - `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` ?

Comment: I try but unfortunatly it's change nothing (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related to this? http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e262c912-5250-4996-acbc-41a8bcd11ba0/weird-ie-behavior-when-combining-drop-shadow-and-radius-css?forum=ieitprocurrentver

Answer suggests a graphics driver problem:

> I turned off GPU rendering in the Advanced options and after I rebooted,  the radius with drop shadow displays just fine....

Comment: exactly !! it's this !! thanks you a lot! !!! if i turn off GPU rendering then it's ok !! but what to do ? i can not ask all the internet users to disable their GPU rendering ( i use the last driver for my nvidia graphic card that is very common graphic card :(

Comment: yeah, annoying. At least the problem is out there so hopefully they'll fix it. In the meantime if you really wanted to you could try adding the shadow to a different element that doesn't have a border radius, e.g. an otherwise invisible div. Maybe use :after/:before rather than messing up your html... Unfortunately I can't reproduce the problem here so I can only speculate about what might work.

Answer (score 0):

this solution in works in ie11

```
div {
   -moz-border-radius: 10px; /* Firefox */
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px; /* Safari, Chrome */
   -khtml-border-radius: 10px; /* KHTML */
    border-radius: 10px; /* CSS3 */
   -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
   -moz-box-shadow:    4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
   box-shadow:         4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
   background:rgba(50, 50, 50);
}
```

Comment: you add <!DOCTYPE html> ?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hkEBt Here is the link I checked on her win 7 and ie11 its WORKS!!!!!

Comment: otherwise you that something is wrong with ie11 bug